# Counterexample to show the map $a \mapsto -a$ is not a binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

The text in Dummit and Foote on pg-$16$ says:

> $-$ (usual subtraction) is a non-commutative binary operation on
>   $\mathbb{Z}$,  where $-(a, b) = a-b$. The map $a \mapsto -a$ is not a
>   binary operation (not binary).

I understand how subtraction is non-commutative. For example, $(-3)-(2)\neq (2)-(-3)$
How can I show by counterexample that the map $a \mapsto -a$ is not a binary operation?

Thanks.

Comment: It only takes one operand, not two.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I see that. I have just quoted the text. Is that the only reason why it is not binary?

Comment: Yes, it just goes back to basic definitions--what, formally, is a binary operation? Does the unary minus satisfy the definition of a binary operation?

Comment: And a counterexample isn't really what you need--just show that it doesn't satisfy the definition.

Comment: @Ritu: literally, "binary operator" means "acting on two operands."

Comment: If that is so, then can we say that any function in single variable is not a binary operation while any function in two variables may be a binary operation?

Comment: [(as long as they take values in the same set, yes, I reckon)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinaryOperation.html)

Comment: An $n$-ary operation $f$ on $\,S\,$ is a function $\,f : S^n \to S.\,$ For $\,n=1,2,3\,$ arguments they are called unary,binary,ternary operations on $\,S$. Constants like $0,1$ are sometimes viewed as $0$-ary operations.

Comment: I have a different question, but what is the point of the statement that "the map is not a binary operation" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary operation takes two inputs.  The map $a\mapsto -a$ only takes one input.